# Windows not booting in dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, boot-repair

I have dual Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 installed in my PC.
I installed Ubuntu after Windows, and I have issues with GRUB. After installing Ubuntu, there was no boot loader in the start up, with an error message about missing OS.
I tried boot repair, I can see the GRUB loader now and can access Ubuntu, uut I am not able to access Windows, even though I can see that in GRUB loader.

I tried to fix the Windows start up with my Windows Live CD, but that removed the GRUB.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Please run Boot-Repair's `Recommended Repair`, then indicate the URL that will appear. This will give us valuable information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening Ubuntu terminal and executing command

> sudo update-grub

Comment: This worked for me in a similar situation. At the next boot, I held Shift until I got "Missing operating system". Rebooted again, and GRUB showed the list of options, including Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could add a boot entry for Ubuntu in Windows Boot Configaration Data (BCD) store using this [guide](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html) and so create a dual-boot under control of Windows boot manager.

or

2) With Ubuntu Live CD reinstall GRUB2 using this [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=224351) so this would create a dual-boot under control of GRUB.

Comment: He already reinstalled grub when he used boot-repair.

Comment: Yes, he reinstalled Grub but then he has used Windows CD to overwrite Grub again....

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you accidentally removed your boot loader for windows. You need to get a windows repair disc and use it to restore your boot loader. It is fairly simple to do but you need the disc.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the problem like you and this is the way that I followed to fix it.

http://milindapro.blogspot.com/2012/01/revert-ubuntu-boot-loader-after.html

The simple answer is just re-install the grub loader. It will add all the operating systems on your system to boot menu.

Thanks